# How to configure jOOQ auto generator to run on basis of liquibase schema xml file?

Tags: java, maven, liquibase, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I want jOOQ auto-code generator to run on basis of liquibase schema xml file located in resources folder (not on basis of database connection). The configuration part looks like this in pom.xml:

```xml
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.13.4.xsd">
    <generator>
        <database>
            <name>org.jooq.meta.extensions.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabase</name>
            <includes>.*</includes>
            <excludes></excludes>
            <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>

            <properties>
                <property>
                    <key>scripts</key>
                    <value>/liquibase-outputChangeLog.xml</value>
                </property>

                <property>
                    <key>includeLiquibaseTables</key>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>

                <property>
                    <key>database.liquibaseSchemaName</key>
                    <value>public</value>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </database>

        <target>
            <packageName>jooqGenerated</packageName>
            <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
        </target>
    </generator>
</configuration>
```

It is not able to generate jOOQ code in the specified folder, says

```
[ERROR] azure/postgresql/TrackerAzureImpl.java: package ...tables does not exist (for all the tables, I cannot even see elsewhere where jooq code is getting generated),
Also one warning: No schemata were loaded: [WARNING] No schemata were loaded  : Please check your connection settings, and whether your database (and your database version!) is really supported by jOOQ. Also, check the case-sensitivity in your configured <inputSchema/> elements : {=[public]}
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely due to a bug: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12997

#### Explanation and workaround

Behind the scenes, in jOOQ 3.16, the `LiquibaseDatabase`, `DDLDatabase`, and `JPADatabase` all simulate your database migrations using an in-memory H2 database. This might be changed in the future, but that's how it works now. In H2, by default, all identifiers are in upper case, and so is the `<inputSchema/>` configuration. This means you should be including the `PUBLIC` schema, not the `public` schema.

Note that also code generation output will contain references to `PUBLIC`, not `public`, so if you want to continue using the `LiquibaseDatabase`, you'll have to turn off quoting of identifiers at runtime using the [`RenderQuotedNames` setting](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-name-style/).

#### More robust alternative that doesn't simulate Liquibase on H2

Alternatively, you don't *have to* use the `LiquibaseDatabase`, as I've mentioned elsewhere. You can also use testcontainers to run an actual migration directly on PostgreSQL, and reverse engineer an actual PostgreSQL database, instead, [as described in this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/using-testcontainers-to-generate-jooq-code/).

Comment: Actually you're right. I am facing the exact same issues that you have mentioned. At first, I thought that my use case is not so much that H2 cannot suffice. But I faced all this, that Public Schema not found, Quoted identifiers at Runtime, all identifiers are in uppercase, etc.
I think then that there are three ways for me: Either check in the generated jooq code or write POJOs myself instead of using codegen or to explore TestContainers.